# How to create a group of text fields like in the Facebook login screen?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a screen with a picture and a label in the top part and somewhere in the middle i want to add two textfields. I really like the way Facebook login screen looks and i would like to do something similar but that is not too easy for me, being an absolute beginner.

I am using Storyboards and the view controller for the current screen implements UIViewController.

I would like to understand how to manage it, so, any tips are apreaciated.

Thanks.

LE:This is what i have tried, but with no result:
I added a table view on the screen and i created properties for the two text fields so i can dynamically add the two text field in the 2 cells.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 2;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if( cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        self.txtUsername = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 20)];
        self.txtUsername .placeholder = @"Username";
        self.txtUsername .autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        [self.txtUsername setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
        cell.accessoryView = self.txtUsername ;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        self.txtPassword = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 20)];
        self.txtPassword.placeholder = @"Password";
        self.txtPassword.secureTextEntry = YES;
        self.txtPassword.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        [self.txtPassword setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
        cell.accessoryView = self.txtPassword;
    }


    [cell addSubview:self.txtUsername];
    [cell addSubview:self.txtPassword];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return 1;
}
```

I am not using Static cells so i figured it out the only way is to programatically add those text fields.

Should i user Static cells?

Comment: Can you upload a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you are looking to do can be easy achieved with a `tableView` and just insert your text fields inside of your cells. Give this documentation on table views a read for a better understanding on how they work : [Apple's Documentation on Table View Programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

If you are working on storyboards like stated in your description, then you will want to delete the delegate methods you have in your view controller (the code that you posted) for the table view, the app will not work this way.

Sounds like what you are trying to achieve can be done with Static cells, therefore You shouldn't use the data source methods.

Comment: So you are doing this programmatically or using storyboards like you originally posted? Because your updated question description will not work if you are setting up your view in Storyboards.

Comment: I do not use Static cells, from what i have read they work only with UITableViewController. In the storyboard, i added only a table view with 2 rows and in the controller i programatically add the text fields

Comment: Yes you are correct, static cells only work with a UITableViewController, I was suggesting that you use one for your intended purpose as it would not only be a better way of achieving the result you are looking for, it will also look / function better.